# Latitude & longitude universal format

Tags: database-design, migration, datatypes, spatial

I don't know yet what database I'll use in the future - MySql, Postgresql, Sqlite3 or anything else. At the moment I'm using a database N.

What's more or less universal approach for storing latitude & longitude? Varchar? Or big integer? Or float?

Should I store them in 2 columns or one?

Answer (score 3):

Neither. The right answer is to use the GIS Spatial Type for a point. All of those databases have their own implementation.

[PostgreSQL's PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography) is easily the most full featured GIS implementation,

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
  gid  int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  geog geography(POINT)
);
```

I would highly suggest going PostgreSQL, and checking out the book [PostGIS in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/postgis-in-action-second-edition) if you're new to this.
See also,

- [My comparison of MySQL and PostgreSQL's PostGIS for spatial](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/191336/2639)
- [MySQL Spatial Data Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html) (which suck btw),
- [SQLite Spatial Extension SpatiaLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index)

Comment: As of 5.7.x `mysql` has the proper set of MBR* and ST_* functions. I had no time to test them in production but it look way more promising than earlier unusable stub.