# Oracle GIS database replacement

Tags: oracle, spatial

My company has a huge (hundreds of millions of records) Oracle database of GIS/temporal information.  We are trying to switch to an open source alternative.

If it helps, we imagined the following requirements:

1. horizontal scaling (like elastic search, for example)
2. fully SQL compliant. We don't think we can use NoSQL, etc, because we would have to rewrite all our queries.
3. No license fee

Comment: The obvious choice is PostgreSQL/postgis but this question is entirely too vague.

Comment: What additional details can I provide?

Comment: From my perspective you have only two options MySQL and PostgreSQL. And MySQL is not really an option, because MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

No database is fully SQL compliant. But out of the SQL databases that provide any form of scaling you have PostgreSQL w/ PostGIS and MySQL to choose from.

PostGIS is the superior choice. For why [see my comparison here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/191336/2639).

Comment: Ok.  You linked answer has convinced me not to use MySQL.  One of the things we are hearing is switching to  "cattle not pets" cloud paradigm.  Can postgresql support that?

Comment: @Craeft sure if you want to use Amazon RDS. I wouldn't off the shelf PostgreSQL likely works just fine for you

Comment: @Craeft: for horizontal scaling you might want to look at https://www.citusdata.com/ not only Amazon. Here is an overview on cloud providers for Postgres: https://severalnines.com/blog/comparing-cloud-database-options-postgresql